# Monoid with inversion

Tags: group-theory, terminology, inverse, monoid

Is there a name for monoid with operation $a\mapsto a^{-1}$ conforming the equations $(a^{-1})^{-1}=a$ and $(b\cdot a)^{-1} = a^{-1}\cdot b^{-1}$? (with no requirement that $a^{-1}\cdot a$ would be identity)?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is called a **monoid with involution**, though the phrase **[semigroup with involution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup_with_involution)** is more popular. Involutions don't have to have anything to do with inverses.

If you wanted $a \cdot a^{-1} \cdot a = a$ and $a^{-1} \cdot a \cdot a^{-1} = a^{-1}$, then you get an **[inverse monoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_monoid)**.

For instance in the semigroup with 0 of all (possibly rectangular) matrices, the transpose is an involution, but the [pseudo-inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse) $A \mapsto A^t(AA^t)^{-1}$ makes it an inverse monoid once you fix several problems with my abridged definition).